# Images disappear after import thru Magmi on Magento 1.9.1

Tags: import, image, magmi, product-images, image-upload

I am having an abnormal issue after i upload the images, i can see them in the front and back end. However, after few minutes pass, the images disappear from the backend  and the product no longer show image under manage prodcut page in the IMAGES tab. Perhaps its a magento issue then magmi?

One scenario, when i manually uploaded the images for configurable and simple product. This actually held up and kept the images from disappearing. I cant open and save all the products manually, any other way to mass update images?

Does anyone have any idea why the images arent staying put after importing thru magmi? I am using magmi v0.7.22_git (latest git version) I tired other older verions but the problem remains. This started happening, i believe after i upgraded magento to 1.9.1 from 1.9.0.1, but haven't heard from anyone else having this issue.

Comment: I've never had this issue on Magmi v0.7.18 or on CE 1.9.1. I'm going to guess third-party extension or program.

Comment: Problem is in the images import, when you using the same image for more than one product. Magmi build-in module Image attributes processor can handle individual image names for import.

Answer (score 3):

the truth is,images were not deleted,but only filename removed from database because the default catalog module remove duplicate image

so,the problem solving is below

override module "Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media" into your own module
 step: in file media.php 
in function loadGallery($product,$object){ 
//$this->_removeDuplicates($result); please comment this
 }

this solved my cases

Answer (score 1):

It's a new image storage mechanism in Magento 1.9 - "media gallery". Magmi is not aware of it, so Magento probably marks the images as orphans and cleans them up.

It's a known Magmi issue waiting to be fixed: [#183](https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git/issues/183) (there is a couple of workarounds mentioned there).

Answer (score 0):

Hope you got the memo...

> Unsecure Magmi Data Import Tool It has also come to our attention that
>   some sites use the Magmi data import tool without protection from
>   outside access. This tool can be abused to gain full access to a
>   Magento installation and ***it is critical that you act now and remove
>   this tool from your production website or limit access to it based on
>   IP address or password***.
>
> Security Resource You can also check your site for other security
>   vulnerabilities at http://magereport.com. This is a Magento community
>   project that is not affiliated with Magento.